# How to use D3 json or csv with React component.

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

Normally I write like below, when it comes to D3.

```
var q = d3.queue()
    q.defer(d3.json, "/data/tokyo.json")
      .defer(d3.csv,  "/data/city_name.csv")
      .await(mainFunc);

function mainFunc(_error, _json, _csv){
  .....
}
```

However I have no idea how to write code in React Component.
It should be imported like this.

```
import {queue} from 'd3-queue'
import {json} from 'd3-json' // <- There is no npm package.
import {csv} from 'd3-csv'   // <- There is no npm package.

var q = d3.queue()
    q.defer(json, "/data/tokyo.json")
      .defer(csv,  "/data/city_name.csv")
      .await(mainFunc);
```

However there are no `npm` module like `d3-json` and `d3-csv`.
How can I write code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You import the name `queue` but then you don't use it anywhere. Instead you use the name `d3` which you did not import at all. The npm package you are searching for is [d3-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-request):

```
import {queue} from 'd3-queue';
import {json, csv} from 'd3-request';
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: _d3Queue.queue.defer is not a function` happend in `queue.defer(json.json, "/data.json")`.

Comment: I figured out. It should be `queue().defer(json, "/data.json")` . Thanks.